# What are in memory elements in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

I have couple of documents on which `xdmp:node-replace()` over certain elements doesnot work. There are some other set of documents which are almost similar to the ones that has problem but `xdmp:node-replace` works perfectly fine on them. Tried all possibilities that could have gone wrong but in vain. Read some where that `xdmp:node-replace` function does not work on '**in memory elements**'.

So in order to verify whether the issue is with '**in memory elements**', I want to know what exactly it is.

Any light on it would be of great help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything constructed within a query is an in-memory element. For example this XQuery yields an in-memory element:

```
<test/>
```

Some function calls also return in-memory elements: `xdmp:unquote` is an obvious example. Any node that doesn't come from the current database will be treated as an in-memory node.

This query yields a database element (if it exists), which could be modified using `xdmp:node-replace`:

```
doc('fubar')/test
```

This is a typical in-memory update error:

```
xdmp:node-replace(<x/>, <y/>)
```

With MarkLogic 6.0-1.1, the error code is `XDMP-UPCONSTNODES`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to update in-memory nodes as if they were in the database by using similar function calls, there's a utility library that does that:

https://github.com/marklogic/commons/tree/master/memupdate

The main library also ships with MarkLogic Server under App Services:

appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy

Comment: For a slightly more optimized version of that library, see: https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations

Answer (score 2):

If your working with `in memory elements` import the following module

`import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update"     at  "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";`

Instead of using `xdmp:node-replace` you can use `mem:node-replace(<x/>, <y/>)`