# Not picking up modifications to an XML document in the database

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have only just started with MarkLogic and XQuery. I am having a really tough time in modifying the content of one of my XML documents. I just cannot seem to get a change to an element to pick up. Here's my process (I have had to take things back as basic as I could just to try and get it working):

In query console I have one tab open which queries for the contents of one XML doc:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
xdmp:document-get("C:/Users/Paul/Documents/MarkLogic/xml/ppl/ppl/jdbc_ppl_3790.xml")
```

This brings back the document as below

false 
    
    
    ...
    3790

```
Victoria Wilson 
</ppl_name>
```

I now want to update the  element using XQuery but it's just not happening. Here's the XQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

let $docxml := 
xdmp:document-get("C:/Users/Paul/Documents/MarkLogic/xml/ppl/ppl/jdbc_ppl_3065.xml")/document/meta/ppl_name
return
  for $node in $docxml/*
  let $target := xdmp:document-get("C:/Users/Paul/Documents/MarkLogic/xml/ppl/ppl/jdbc_ppl_3790.xml")/document/meta/*[fn:name() = fn:name($node)]
  return
  xdmp:node-replace($target, $node)
```

I am basically looking to replace the `ppl_name` element in the target (3790) with the `ppl_name` element from the source (3065).

I run the XQuery - it completes without error (making me thing it has worked) - return value reads `your query returned an empty sequence`.

I then go back to the same tab as I used in step 1 and re-run the XQuery used in step 1. The doc (3790) comes back but it STILL has Victoria Wilson as the `ppl_name`.

Answer (score 2):

The node returned by `xdmp:document-get` is an in-memory node from a document on the filesystem. It isn't coming from the database. You can't use `xdmp:node-replace` on in-memory nodes. That's only for database-resident nodes.

You can insert it using `xdmp:document-insert`. Then it's in the database, and you can access it using `doc` and update it using `xdmp:node-replace`. Or you can use in-memory operations to construct a new version with the changes you want.

See [What are in memory elements in marklogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583130/what-are-in-memory-elements-in-marklogic) for previous answers to a similar question, and more tips.

Answer (score 1):

Here the node returned by `xdmp:document-get` is an `in-memory node`
If your working with `in memory elements` import the following module

`import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";`

Instead of using `xdmp:node-replace` you can use `mem:node-replace(<x/>, <y/>)`