# When I try to update a node I get the error "Cannot Update constructed nodes"

Tags: xquery, marklogic

When I try to update a node using the XQuery below I get the error:

> XDMP-UPCONSTNODES: xdmp:node-replace(...) "Cannot Update constructed nodes"

```
let $_ := xdmp:node-replace($mydoc/docVersions, $otherVersions)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583130/what-are-in-memory-elements-in-marklogic

Comment: If you're trying to boost the findability of this answer, include the error code `XDMP-UPCONSTNODES` - or whatever error code you see.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the built in node-replace doesn't work on in-memory documents.

You can use the in-mem-update.xqy versions to do this.

```
import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at '/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy';

let $_ := mem:node-replace($mydoc/docVersions, $otherVersions)
```